# Yii2 Gridview : Object of class ... could not be converted to string

Tags: php, arrays, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I tried to display data from table 'Event' to a GridView, I have tried `ActiveDataProvider` and `ArrayDataProvider` but both give me this error.

> PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException - Object of class ...
>   could not be converted to string

Can someone explain what should I fix from this code?

```
          <?= 
                $query = new Query(); 
                $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                    'query' => $query->from('event')->all(),
                ]);

                GridView::widget([
                    'id' => 'gridEvent',
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'columns' => [
                        'name',
                        'address',
                        'started_at',
                        'ended_at',
                    ],
                ]);
            ?>
```

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html), `ArrayDataProvider` does not have a `query` properity, it has `allModels` instead

Comment: thank you @gmc for your response, I have change it to allModels but still got the error.

Comment: remove `->all()` from `$query->from('event')->all()` just use `$query->from('event')` to pass to the `query` param

Comment: thank you @MuhammadOmerAslam for your response, I have remove it but still got the error. The error page is focusing in this line $query = new Query();

Comment: have you added `use \yii\db\Query` on top of your page ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes I have

Comment: and what does the error say?

Comment: did you solved the problem

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I'm sorry for not updating and making you wait. I have done things that you suggest me to do but still got the problem, so I decide to avoid using any data provider by using arrayhelper and bootstrap table.

Comment: nah thats ok, I just saw my answer and realized that i added the `$dataProvider` with `ArraydataProvider` and actually it should be `ActiveDataProvider` , i am just **SO SORRY** `:(` because the solution that i tested is with `ActiveDataProvider` and not `ArrayDataProvider`  because `query` property is only in `ActiveDataProvider` and in my code below i wrote `ArrayDataProvider` although in description i never used the term `ArrayDataProvider` i just updated my answer it should work, otherwise i am getting a ticket and coming over there to fix it , so sorry for this inconvenience

Comment: my first code section should work on your end now

Comment: hello, hope your problem was solved. Can you mark the answer as accepted / correct if it worked for you, so others having the same problem might also benefit

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `use yii\db\Query` on top or try giving full namespace while calling the function `new \yii\db\Query()` and you do not need the `->all()` when providing to the `query` value for `ActiveDataProvider` you need to provide the object to it not the result set.

```
<?= 
    $query = new \yii\db\Query(); 

    $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query->from('event'),
    ]);

    GridView::widget([
        'id' => 'gridEvent',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            'name',
            'address',
            'started_at',
            'ended_at',
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

Just verified it is working on my end,

**EDIT**

if you still run into same error try running the following provided by [**`guide-db-query-builder`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html)

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(['id', 'email']) 
->from('user') 
->limit(10) 
->all(); 

print_r($rows);
```

and if it still says the same then there is a strong possibility that you might have to just remove the directory `vendors` and run `composer update` to install again because it seems like something is wrong with your setup.

Comment: regarding your comment to my question the error says the same : yii\db\Query could not be converted to string. I have tried your code but the error still there. is it possible that it's corrupted or something?

Comment: that is awkward , are you sure it is on the same line where you initiate object for the `Query` and have you the same code as i have provided? plus go to `terminal` and type `./yii` and check what version do you have

Comment: my yii version 2.0.13.1.

Comment: this is really strange :/ as I have refreshed and checked many times on my end it works perfect and have the same version `2.0.13`, can you run this query and check what is the result `$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->from('user')
    ->limit(10)
    ->all();` try `print_r($rows);` and check if it is showing you the user records @ni50

Comment: you need to remove the vendors and run again `composer update`

Comment: I'm sorry, which one should I remove ?

Comment: just remove the directory `vendors` and run composer to install again because it seems like something is wrong with your setup as the query I provided you is the one provided by [**`guide-db-query-builder`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html)  and it gives the same error at your end which should not be the case @ni50